# Add calling and sms to Vodafone Dongle K3772

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem, modem-manager, sms

I have a Vodafone 3G Dongle which I use to connect to internet on my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop.
All is working fine. Now I want to add sms and call facility to this device so that I could make calls directly from my laptop or send sms and receive the same.

I works fine in windows with latest Mobile Partner Application from Huawei.

How it can be done on Ubuntu ?
Also If you will be suggesting Gammu or Wammu, please help me with the steps involved, as I tried this but nothing happened..

Answer (score 0):

You can SMS through `vodafone-mobile-broadband` package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:crass/v-mobile-broadband
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install v-mobile-broadband
```

Comment: I already have 'Modem Manager GUI'. But while sending sms, its gives error as, **Error sending message, GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager.Modem.Connectec: Cannot perform this operation while connected**